# QGraphicsOpacityEffect on QTextField on Windows 7 -- strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am attempting to add a fade-in/fade-out effect to a widget (that contains other widgets, including buttons and text fields).
The problem is that while buttons fade perfectly, text fields do not - instead of changing opacity of the text field, only the opacity of its border changes.If the text has been selected before changing opacity, after the opacity is reduced, the selection looks strange.

What can be the cause of this problem and how to make the fade effect on all widgets, not only push buttons?

The problem can be easily reproduced, if you place a QTextField on form, and add the following code to button handlers:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
       QGraphicsOpacityEffect * effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->plainTextEdit);
    effect->setOpacity(0.1);
    ui->plainTextEdit->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
}
```

After this code is run, you will see something like this:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a9Xg.png)

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
       QGraphicsOpacityEffect * effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->plainTextEdit);
    effect->setOpacity(1.0);
    ui->plainTextEdit->setGraphicsEffect(effect);

}
```

The text field looks like this, after this method is executed:
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC7Tx.png)

Thanks.

Comment: I saw same question on other forums. Seems, that it is a bug.

Comment: Probably that was me posting this question :)...

Comment: On Russian forums too ;)